# @ExceptionHandler not catching exceptions being thrown from Spring Formatters

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a controller that serves as REST web service and one of my methods is expecting a model which in this model I have a member variable of type `MyObjectId`.

```
public class MyModel {

    private MyObjectId objectId;

    public MyObjectId getMyObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setMyObjectId(final MyObjectId objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }
}
```

I have a custom implementation of a `Formatter` (org.springframework.format) for MyObjectId and this is my parse method:

```
@Override
public MyObjectId parse(final String text, final Locale locale) throws ParseException {
    // If the string is invalid it will throw an IllegalArgumentException
    return MyObjectIdConvertor.convert(text);
}
```

In my spring-servlet.xml I registered my formatter:

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="formatters">
        <set>
            <bean class="com.foo.MyObjectIdFormatter"/>
        </set>
    </property>    
</bean>
```

Now my problem is that when an exception is thrown from the Formatter it is not being caught by any of the `@ExceptionHandler` methods. Therefore the response is being output in this format:

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors Field error in object 'filterModel' on field 'myObjectId': rejected value [foo123123]; codes [typeMismatch.filterModel.myObjectId,typeMismatch.myObjectId,typeMismatch.com.foo.MyObjectId,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [filterModel.myObjectId,myObjectId]; arguments []; default message [myObjectId]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.MyObjectId' for property 'myObjectId'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type com.MyObjectId for value 'foo123123'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "foo123123"]
```

How can I make this type of exception begin caught by an `@ExceptionHandler`. 
This one of my exception handler methods:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(final Exception ex) {

    LOG.error("Error handling request", ex);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(StringUtils.hasText(ex.getMessage()) ? ex.getMessage() : "Error handling request", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation

I don't handle the `Formatter` exception in the `@Controller`

Checking the following:

```
codes [typeMismatch.filterModel.myObjectId,typeMismatch.myObjectId,typeMismatch.com.foo.MyObjectId,typeMismatch];
```

I suggest you work around `ValidationMessages.properties` (you need configure `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` and `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`)

For example I have

```
typeMismatch.person.dateBirth=Invalid data, format for Date of Birth is incorrect!
```

Then assuming if the wise and friendly user writes an invalid date according the formatter, my `DateFormatter` class, like in your case throws an exception, but since I have defined the code `typeMismatch.person.dateBirth` the error message is show in my web form.

Observe our codes are similar in some way. I *think* Spring looks somewhere if some of the `codes` exists to show an appropriate message, since you have none code the exception stack trace remains, in my case how I have the code and the customized message, it is presented in my web form.

I didn't test yet how that customized error message should fit well through `REST`. But in my case if some `Formatter` throws an error I am sure that the `code` exists in the `ValidationMessages.properties` file.